# pusher class not found when install tcpdf and maatwebsite/excel via composer

Tags: composer-php, laravel-5.3, tcpdf, pusher, maatwebsite-excel

when installing pusher via composer it works !

```
composer require pusher/pusher-php-server
```

but when installing **elibyy/tcpdf-laravel** and **maatwebsite/excel** via composer >> pdf and excel works but pusher not !!

error >> Class Pusher not found !!

composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.3.*",
    "caouecs/laravel-lang": "~3.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^5.3.0",
    "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "6.25.0",
    "laravel/socialite": "2.0.21",
    "musonza/chat": "^1.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2",
    "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^3.0",
    "illuminate/support": "5.3.*",
    "tecnickcom/tcpdf": "6.2.12",
    "elibyy/tcpdf-laravel": "5.3.0",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "2.1.*"
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By any change have you upgraded Pusher from 2.x version to 3.0.0? They have introduced namespace so try:

```
new \Pusher\Pusher($auth_key, $secret, $app_id);
```

or import it:

```
<?php

use Pusher\Pusher;
// ...

$pusher = new Pusher($auth_key, $secret, $app_id);
```